# How can i find an item in a list then return its pair?

Tags: haskell

I have a list, like this [('A',1),('B',2),..]
I'd like to do a key value search. 
I already found the lookup but it returns a 'Maybe Int'.
So are there any function which returns the value for the key, and gives a normal int back?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the key doesn't exist in the lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What should the function do in case the key is not in the list?

If you are sure the key is in the list, then

```
import Data.Maybe
```

and run the result (i.e. the Maybe Int) through `fromJust`. You'll get a plain Int, and when the key is not in the list you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

What would you like it to return if the key isn't in the list?

There is a reason that lookup returns a `Maybe Int` rather than an Int - to force the programmer to deal with the failure case.

An easy way of dealing with the maybe is with a default value, for example:

```
withDefaultValue = fromMaybe 0 (lookup key myList)
```

If you are 100% sure that the value is in the list, you can use `fromJust`

```
result = fromJust (lookup key myList)
```

If the list might not contain the item, but you can't deal with the failure in your code in that function, pass the `Maybe` out of your function until it reaches the part of the code that can deal with the failure.